# node, azuresb.createServiceBusService provide connection string instead of environment variable

Tags: node.js, azureservicebus

I'm using the package azure-sb to send a message to an Azure Service Bus topic.  My problem is that the constructor expects a key for a connection string for example

```
azuresb.createServiceBusService(KEY_NAME)
```

Is it possible to provide the connection string itself instead of a KEY_NAME?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. From the documentation of this package, you do need to pass the connection string.

```
var connStr = process.argv[2] || process.env.CONNECTION_STRING;
var sbService = azure.createServiceBusService(connStr);
```

[Microsoft Azure SDK for Node.js - Gallery](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-sb) https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure-sb

Also, azuresb seems an older SDKs. If you use [Azure SDK for Node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/azure), here is how you can pass the connection string (quite similar!)

```
var serviceBusService = azure.createServiceBusService(connectionString)
```

*You might have found the answer already... adding it here if someone else visits your question in future*. :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the other answers, you can pass the connection string. Your code seems to be using the older `azure-sb` library.

I'd recommend using the latest `@azure/service-bus` library which is based on AMQP protocol and is more performant.

I know this is a late reply, but just in case someone is running into issues with the older service-bus node SDK and landed here, refer to the links below.

The latest version 7.0.0 of `@azure/service-bus` has been released recently.

- [@azure/service-bus - 7.0.0](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/service-bus)
- [Samples for 7.0.0](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/tree/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/samples)
- [Guide to migrate from @azure/service-bus v1 to v7](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/master/sdk/servicebus/service-bus/migrationguide.md)